# Firebase Function .pubsub.schedule first weekday of month

Tags: firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I want to run my scheduled firebase function on the first weekday of each month.

I have tried `.pubsub.schedule("0 9 1W * *")`, `.pubsub.schedule("0 9 * * 1W")`, and `.pubsub.schedule('0 9 1W * ?')` all of which do not work.

Answer (score 2):

As per the GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules), the recurring intervals should be specified using the [unix-cron](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) format - you don't need `W` in there.

If you wanted to run the function on the first day of each month (i.e. once a month) at 9:00 AM, the correct format would be `0 9 1 * *`.

However, for the scenario you described, you will need to be calculating what day exactly is the first weekday of a month. Here are some articles that you may find helpful for that: [link1](https://www.switchplane.com/editorial/2009/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-weekday-of-the-month/), [link2](https://superuser.com/questions/1042805/how-to-set-cron-expression-to-run-first-weekday-mon-fri-and-first-weekend-sat).